# Is motion conserved?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, conservation-laws, terminology

In physics it is said that there is a law of '[conservation of energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy)'. Also there is a law of 'conservation of [momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum)'.

I am interested in the term or concept of 'MOTION'. I think motion is related to 'velocity' (v) (similar to speed), or 'momentum' (mass multiplied by velocity) (p=mv).

---

I think it is arguable that fundamental forces (or fundamental interactions) such as 'electromagnetism' and 'gravity', by definition, 'can put more matter into motion over more time' (or put infinite mass into motion over infinite time), and thus motion doesn't have to be conserved over time.

Another argument against conservation of motion may be that human has the ability to move from intelligence or free will. Using intelligence or free will, a human can create a motion (with magnitude and direction) that was not going to exist. But a criticism may be that humans cannot move more than the energy they get for example from food.

---

Is motion conserved?

Comment: have you read Newton's laws of motion? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion

Comment: Define "conservation of motion" in your question.

Comment: I think we have to define the motion. What can be conserved in physics? Note that the physical quantities are quantities which have physical dimensions e.g. length, time, mass. Hence we have to define the motion as a quantity with some dimension. Newton's laws of inertia states the velocity (dimension = $[{\rm LT}^{-1}]$ is conserved.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, according to Newton's first law of motion an object at rest tends to remain at rest until acted upon by another force. And an object in motion will remain in motion at a constant velocity until acted upon by another force. So this could be termed "conservation of motion" although inertial motion and momentum are generally assumed to have the same meaning.

Comment: A slightly different form of this is the center of mass theorem, which relates symmetry under Lorentz boosts with the uniform motion of the center of mass.

Answer (score 3):

*In special relativity* there is a kind of conservation of motion, the conservation of [4-velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity). It is defined as $$\mathbf{u}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}}{\partial \tau}$$ where $\mathbf{x}$ is the coordinates (in four dimensions) of the particle moving, and $\tau$ is [the proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) experienced by it. If you have a object moving with 3-velocity $\mathbf{v}$ then the 4-velocity is $\mathbf{u}=\gamma[c, \mathbf{v}]$ where $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-(||\mathbf{v}||/c)^2}$. The funny thing is that for every matter particle (this does not apply to light or superluminal particles) the length of this 4-dimensional vector is $$||\mathbf{u}||=c.$$

So in special relativity there is conservation of motion. In a sense everything is moving forward in space and time, and we just change our direction, trading "time velocity" for "space velocity".

Now, in Newtonian mechanics there are no such conservation laws. Particles can gain arbitrarily high velocities e.g. by close gravitational encounters.

One can appeal to [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) to see that the translation invariance of Newtonian mechanics leads to momentum conservation, time translation invariance to energy conservation, and rotation invariance to angular momentum conservation. There is no other continuous symmetries in flat 3-space to use (since I think screw displacements don't count? I have at least never seen anybody describe a conserved quantity for the symmetry).

Comment: Great answer, I have one question/remark though: Isn't the magnitude of four-velocity $c$ as opposed to $c^2$ in your answer? (I am not very familiar with such concepts but remember to have read that "we move at the speed of light through spacetime")

Comment: Ah, my finger slipped when copying the equation. I will correct it.

Answer (score 1):

If it counts as motion, then specifically during purely elastic collisions we have, apart from momentum conservation, also, shall we call it **"speed difference" conservation**:

$$v_{1A}-v_{1B}=-(v_{2A}-v_{2B})$$

This is a result of the kinetic energies being conserved by definition in purely elastic collisions, combined with the general momentum conservation law.